# Milliliters of sulphuric acid used to prepare an acid

Tags: volume

How many ml of 95% w/w sulphuric acid having a specific gravity of 1.820 should be used in preparing 2 liters of 10% w/v acid?

The answer is 115.67 ml of 95%
I would like to know the solution. Thanks!

Comment: The solution is 10% sulphuric acid.

Answer (score 1):

we have $95$ g of h2so4 in $100$ g of water that is $95$g  in $54.95$ml of water that $172.88$g in $100$ml of water. Now we can calculate molarity of this solution which is $17.64M$. Now let $x$ml of such solution  be taken. Also molarity of resulting solution is$1.020M$ thus using $M_1V_1=M_2V_2$ we have $x(17.64)=1.020 \times(2000 ml)$ thus $x=115.65$ml rounding error caused a deviation so that should work fine if you increase the accuracy.

Comment: I just have trouble figuring how you came up with the molarity of 17.64M and the molarity of the resulting solution which is 1.020 M. If you could help me out that would be great.

Comment: See we have $172.88$g ie $\frac {172.88}{98}=1.764$ moles thus there are $1.764$ moles in $100$ ml thus $17.64$ moles in $1000$ ml ie molarity is $17.64$M.